# Install Python 3.5.2, but pip for Python 2.6

Tags: python, centos, pip

VPS-server was a version Python 2.6, I installed version Python 3.5.2.
When I try to install some packages with help `pip`, I got errors.

During installation packages:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
```

Versions:

```
# Python -V
# Python 3.5.2

# pip -V
# pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)

# cat /etc/*-release
# CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
```

How to change path to pip from python 3.5 ?

Comment: Did you try: sudo pip3 install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you haven't pip in server you can use [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) file:

after install python usually installed pip and you can run by `pip3` command

for example you can use:

```
pip3 install netaddr
```

Comment: pip is already installed:
`# pip -V
# pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)`

Comment: your pip is from python 2.6, you can create virtual env and install pip3 . or install pip3 in server

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading pip manually solved this issue for me once. [Update pip Documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip)

> pip is already installed if you're using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org, but you'll need to upgrade pip.

On Linux or OS X:

```
pip install -U pip
```

On Windows [5]:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/**python2.6**/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.6.egg`